# Persist navigation paths in NavigationSplitView with NavigationStacks

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I have an SwiftUI iOS app that uses `TabView` to display 4 different `NavigationStack`s. Each stack can be navigated into.
To make this app work better on iPad OS I'd like to use a `NavigationSplitView` with a sidebar and a detail view. The sidebar contains a menu with the 4 items that are tabs on iOS. The detail view should contain individual `NavigationStack`s that should retain their view paths.

After having played around with it a bit it seems to me that `NavigationSplitView` is not meant to be used that way. The detail view resets every time I select another menu item in the sidebar. I've tried retaining the individual navigation paths (as `@State`s) in my root view and passing them into the individual `NavigationStack` when creating the detail view. However, it seems like `NavigationSplitView` is resetting the path whenever you switch to another menu item.

Has anybody figured this out?

Comment: SceneStorage is a good option

Comment: I tried that. However, when you put a NavigationStack into the detail view and hand a pre-stored (through SceneStorage) NavigationPath into that NavigationStack the main thread ends up in an endless loop. It seems like there's' a bug in NavigationSplitView

Comment: I think something changed I haven’t had time to look through release notes but Apple used to have an example in their docs with NavigationSplitView and NavigationStack. But I can’t find that example I have looked everywhere.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm having the same issue... haven't found a solution yet. If you do, please share it with us here :)